# Add view dynamically to cells produce issues in table

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

I have this function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 14, width: 400, height: 30))
        label.text = "\(data[indexPath.row])"
        label.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.contentView.addSubview(label)

        return cell
    }
```

Well, with this function I'm adding a list of rows dynamically.
Why dynamically? Because, the number of columns depends of the data.
Don't take focus on that.

The list has 244 elements.
The result is displayed ok, but once I started scrolling, I get this:

[image]

How I can add elements dynamically without get this error?

Comment: uitableview create 10 cell at scroll down recreate cell view

you can using cell.contentView.removeFromSuperview() before addsubview 

or using  cell.textLabel?.text

Comment: if you add it as answer, I would mark it a correct @a.masri

Answer (score -1, accepted):

UITableview create 10 cell at scroll down recreate cell view

You can using
 `cell.contentView.removeFromSuperview()` before `cell.contentView.addSubview(label)` or using `cell.textLabel?.text`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!
        cell.contentView.removeFromSuperview()
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 14, width: 400, height: 30))
        label.text = "\(data[indexPath.row])"
        label.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.contentView.addSubview(label)

        return cell
    }
```

> Note This solution will delete All subview in cell

Comment: This code has a serious bug. This code actually removes the `contentView` of the cell. Do NOT do that. That's really bad. You want to remove just the label added to the `contentView`.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, he is already getting this but he just wants to make sure the quality of this work
,custom cell is a better approach

Comment: I don't understand your comment. You have posted code that has a serious bug. It needs to be fixed.

Comment: This is only part of exercises to learn more about swift.
  so he wanted to the user who asked

Comment: And how does posting fatally flawed code help anyone learn? Remember, your answer is going to be copied and pasted by other people over time. You just need to fix one line of code. Take pride in your answer by doing it correctly.

Comment: I will add a note to my answer ,Thank you for this comment

Answer (score 2):

Cells get reused. You keep adding more and more labels to each cell.

The proper solution is to create a custom cell class that contains the desired label. Then simply set that label's text in `cellForRowAt`. Don't create and add subviews in `cellForRowAt`.

But keep in mind that you may just want to use the provided `textLabel` property of `UITableViewCell`. No need for a custom cell or your own label.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(data[indexPath.row])"

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, hope this works to you!!!

You have to add to your `cellForRowAt` this code:

```
for item in cell.contentView.subviews
    {
        item.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

Just after to get the cell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!

    for item in cell.contentView.subviews
    {
        item.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 14, width: 300, height: 30))
    label.text = "\(data[indexPath.row])"
    label.tag = indexPath.row

    let btn = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom) as UIButton
    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    btn.setTitle("boton", for: .normal)
    btn.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:5, width: 80, height:40)
    //btn.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressed:", for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    btn.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.contentView.addSubview(btn)
    cell.contentView.addSubview(label)

    cell.tag = indexPath.row

    return cell
}
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. A custom cell is a MUCH better approach.

Comment: @maddy, I know, this is only part of exercises to learn more about swift. That is the reason that I wrote in the "dont take focus on the approach", but yes, you right! `custom cell` is a better approach